# Perl LWP::Simple "Name or Service Not Known" error

Tags: perl, lwp

Sometime in the past week I started getting an error with code that takes a URL and retrieves content.

This uses the Perl Module LWP::Simple

There were no changes to the module or to our code. The server host says nothing has changed.

It happens with http or https

It happens on more than domain we host.

It does NOT happen with a URL from another server.

This is the error

```
Result: $VAR1 = bless( { '_content' => 'Can\'t connect to coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com:443 (Name or service not known) Name or service not known at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 52. ',
'_rc' => 500,
 '_headers' => bless( { 'client-warning' => 'Internal response', 'client-date' => 'Sun, 02 Feb 2020 19:40:24 GMT',
 'content-type' => 'text/plain',
 '::std_case' => { 'client-warning' => 'Client-Warning', 'client-date' => 'Client-Date' } }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
 '_msg' => 'Can\'t connect to coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com:443 (Name or service not known)', '_request' => bless( { '_content' => '',
 '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com/online_store/store/images/0000697417.jpg')},
 'URI::https' ),
 '_headers' => bless( { 'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0' },
 'HTTP::Headers' ), '_method' => 'GET' },
 'HTTP::Request' ) },
 'HTTP::Response' );
```

We are trying to access this image, which exists

https://coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com/online_store/store/images/0000697417.jpg

Thanks in advance for looking

Mike

Comment: Do you have LWP::Protocol::https installed?

Comment: Yes, LWP::Protocol::Https version 6.07

This code has been working for years

Comment: Seems like problems in DNS or /etc/hosts.

Comment: Since error 500 is a general server error, I suspect that the problem is on that end and not in the code or the environment running the code.  I know you said that they say nothing changed, but it could be an upgrade or a change to any number of things they don't realize is causing the problem.  Can you pull down the image from your server using curl or some other way to confirm it is accessible?

Comment: perl -MLWP::Simple -e "getprint('https://coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com/online_store/store/images/0000697417.jpg')" works just fine for me. Can you share the code or provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Or run the above command and see what it says. On Linux you must switch the quotes because of the different shell. This one's for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Server people solved it. Not quite sure what they did but it worked.

> > Could a Cpanel update have changed the environment. This did suddenly start happening with no changes to the code on my end.

Yes, there is also a chance for that as cPanel upgrades suitable packages which are needed for the server hosting environment, however they would do that after extensive testing only.
Since the mentioned error also points to 'Name or service not known' there is a chance that resolution is not happening correctly from inside the server. We have slightly added another resolver IP to the server now. Please check & see how it goes at your end.

Comment: Maybe SElinux or similar was blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code retrieved the image without any issue

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::Simple;

my $base = 'https://coloradosportscards.ultimatecardstore.com';
my $url  = $base . '/online_store/store/images/0000697417.jpg';
my $file = $1 if $url =~ m|/(\d+\.jpg)|;

if (is_success(getstore($url, $file))) {
    say "Retrieved $file successfully";
} else {
    say "Couldn't retrieve $file";
}
```